# Filter in ngFor after user click : Angular 6

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular6

Just a quick question here. I'm still a newbie in angular so please. And yes, I have my view page looks something like this.

[image]

Initially, i'm loading my page with all the required data. Now, the problem here is, when the user clicks on any of the name in **"OWNERS"**, the data should be able to filter based on **"user-click"**. For example, if the user click on **"Krishna"** all the campaigns associated with "Krishna" should be filtered and should be able to display in the same page.

My home.component.ts page looks like this.

```js
import { CampaignService } from './../../../services/campaign.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private campaignService : CampaignService ) { }


  Time;
  campaigns;
  

  ngOnInit(){

    setInterval(() => {  
      this.Time = Date.now()
    }, 1000);
   

    this.campaignService.CampaignsInfo()
    .subscribe(response=>{
      this.campaigns = response;
    });

  }
  
}
```

And my home.component.html looks like this:

```html
<campaign-header></campaign-header>

<div class="container-fluid date-time sticky-top">
<div class="container">
 <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0 d-flex justify-content-center radio" >
     <div class="" >
  <input type="radio" checked name="day"> Today
  </div>
  &nbsp;&nbsp;
   <div class="float-left">
  <input type="radio"  name="day"> Commulative
  </div>
     <!-- <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>-->

    </form>
 <div class="d-flex justify-content-end" style="margin-top: -16px;"> 
   <span id="date_time"><i class="zmdi zmdi-calendar-check zmdi-hc-fw"></i> {{Time | date}} &nbsp; <i class="zmdi zmdi-time zmdi-hc-fw"></i> {{ Time | date:'mediumTime' }} </span> 
</div>
</div>
</div>
<br>
<!-- content -->
<div class="container">
    
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
           
            <div class="card campaign border-top wrap"> 
    
   
                <div class="card-body table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-hover mb-0">
    
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="border-top-0">CAMPAIGN </th>
                                <th class="border-top-0">STATUS</th>
                                <th class="border-top-0">DIALED</th>                               
                                <th class="border-top-0">OWNERS</th>
                                <th class="border-top-0"> <span class="invisible">Action</span></th>
                                <!-- <button  mat-button color="primary" routerLink="/campaign-details">CampaignDetails</button> -->
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
   
                        <tbody>
                             
                            <tr *ngFor="let campaign of campaigns?.result">
                                <td><p>{{campaign.CampaignName}}</p>
         <small>{{campaign.DepartmentName}}</small>
        </td>
                                <td>
                                    <small class="text-info">Active</small>
                                </td>
                                <td>
         <p>{{campaign.Dialed}} / <small>1500000</small></p>
         <div class="progress mt-2 w-75">
                                        <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" style="width: 90%;" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
                                    </div>
        </td>
                                
                                <td>
                                    <button class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary"  > {{ campaign.owners }} </button>
         </td>
                                <td class="ml-0 pl-0"><a routerLink="/campaign-details"><img src="../../assets/Images/next.png" class="next" /></a></td>
                            </tr>
                                
        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<br> 
</div>
```

I tried writing the (click) ="someMethod(campaign.Name)" for the button and passed campaign object and tried applying filter there in component.ts page, but no luck. Any help is much appreciated. Much thanks in advance.

**P.S: This is after some research and after implementing the below suggestion.**

I tried implementing a custom pipe, but after click event on owners, i'm getting the following error.

[image]

**For Information:** My debugging value of the pipe after click event looks like this.
[image]

My pipe Looks like this.

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(values: any[], key: string, value: string): any[] {
    if (!values) {
        return [];
    }
    if (!value) {
        return values;
    }
    return values.filter(val =>{
      debugger;
      console.log(values);

      return val.includes(values);
    });
  }
}
```

And my click event and html looks like this:

```js
filterByOwnr(val) {
  this.filter = val;

}
```

```html
<tr *ngFor="let campaign of campaigns?.result | filter : 'OWNERS' : filter;">

  <td>
    <button class="badge badge-pill badge-secondary" (click)="filterByOwnr(campaign.owner)"> {{ campaign.owner}} </button>
  </td>

</tr>
```

Comment: Please post the code of "someMethod()" which you are calling on click event.

Comment: @AkshayKapoor Sir, Can you please check now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom pipe implementation, shouldn't this line:

```
return val.includes(values);
```

Be this instead?

```
return val.CampaignName.includes(value);
```

Comment: Sir, still the same issue.

Comment: Try return val.CampaignName.includes(value);

Comment: Sir, you saved me, thank you. I was struggling with this code for the past 2 days. Appreciate your effort. _/\_

Comment: Glad I could help. I'll update my answer with the correct line, for future reference.

Answer (score 3):

Implement custom filter pipe. **Note** modify custom pipe as per your need.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filter',
})
@Injectable()
export class Filter implements PipeTransform {
    transform(values: any[], key: string, value: string): any[] {
        if (!values) {
            return [];
        }
        if (!key|| !value) {
            return values;
        }

    return values.filter(val=>
        val[key].toLowerCase().includes(value.toLowerCase())
    );
}
```

}

```
import { Filter } from 'filterPipe';

@NgModule({
    imports: [],    
    declarations: [ Filter ],    
    providers: [ ],    
    exports: [
        Filter
    ],
})
export class PipeModule {}

//App module
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PipeModule } from './modules/pipe.module';

@NgModule({
    imports: [PipeModule
    ],

declarations: [
],

providers: [
],

bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Home HTML

```
   <tr *ngFor="let campaign of campaigns?.result | filter : 'OWNERS' : searchVal;">
    <td class="text-left">
        <span (click)="filterByOwnr(campaign.OWNERS)">{{campaign.OWNERS}}</span>
    </td>

filterByOwnr(val){
this.searchVal = val;
}
```

Comment: Sir, i'm getting the following error " ** Cannot find name 'field'. [2304] ** " in my custom pipe.